# AuthLogic gem - how to destroy all sessions?

Tags: ruby, authlogic

I am using the [AuthLogic gem](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) in my ruby app (not rails).
this gem can manage multiple sessions for same user, but, if i want to block a user
from my app, i want to invalidate all his sessions from backend.
currently i can destroy the session only when its active

```
 user_session = UserSession.find
  if user_session
    user_session.destroy
    return {status: 200, message: 'Success'}
  else
    return {status: 400, message: 'No session to destroy'}
  end
```

, but how can i get all user sessions by user id and destroy them?

Comment: this code from controller? please post full listing.

Comment: this code from a route, i use Grape.

Comment: What is `UserSession`? If you have integrated AuthLogic::Session::Base with the data model (ActiveRecord or Sequel I'd guess) then you should be able to fetch other sessions of the same account relatively easily.